# Why is the 4s-complement of 412 (in decimal) 321210?

Tags: bit-manipulation, complement

I used an online converter to convert 412 from decimal to base 4 (which is 12130), and then applied the r's complement formula to get its 4s complement (which is 21210). However, in 6bits, 21210 becomes 321210.

When I try to convert it to decimal by doing
`3 x - 4^5 + 2 x 4^4 + 1 x 4^3 + 2 x 4^2 + 1 x 4^1`,
I get a number in decimal that is way larger than 412.

Comment: Note that a 'bit' usually means a "base two digit" -- in base 4, you have base 4 digits, for which there is not a convenient short name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your "conversion to decimal" wrong -- it should be:

```
-1 x 4^5 + 2 x 4^4 + 1 x 4^3 + 2 x 4^2 + 1 x 4^1
```

note the difference in the first term, dealing with the sign -- the '3' digit has a value of -1 in a 4s complement sign digit.